# Add one milliseconds to the tick

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a tick data as 638315425210000000 and 638338147200000000 need to add/subtract one milliseconds from it, and for the same I'm using the below specified code lines

```
let ticksInMilliseconds = 10000
//to add milliseconds to tick
const startTick = 638315425210000000
const millisecondsAdded = startTick +  ticksInMilliseconds 
//to reduce one millisecond
const endTick = 638338147200000000
const millisecondReduced = endTick - ticksInMilliseconds
```

For millisecondsAdded I get tick value as (638315425210010000) and for millisecondReduced get tick value as 638338147199990000

When converted to dates online to check if the milliseconds value are added/reduced the millisecondReduced gave correct value, but the millisecondsAdded still shows the same time with no milliseconds added 2023-09-29​T00:02:01.000Z

I would like to understand why add is not adding millisecond to the tick and what should be the solution for the same

For conversion online I used https://tickstodatetime.azurewebsites.net/ which accepts the values I paste

Comment: Your number is larger then the [maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), I'd suggest using [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead

Comment: @Reyno can you please help with small example one liner would be helpful

Comment: all those numbers you have in your *code* ... append an `n` ... to use BigInt

Comment: @mplungjan but if i try 638315425210000000 + 11000 and then check it ,it gives me proper time with one millisecond added even without bigint

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. So use the code found at https://github.com/worldwidewat/TicksToDateTime

Comment: new Date(638356403040020000 / 1e+4 + new Date('0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z').getTime()).toISOString()  for time being using this formula for conversion to time and proper value is recieved

Answer (score 0):

your number is above the [max safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) value and operations aren't reliable on integers at that point. You could use a [Big integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to keep precision at that point

Comment: Please do not copy a comment to an answer.

Comment: Can you please help me with a small example

Comment: @mrplungjan I didn't copy it i wrote my answer at the same time

Answer (score 0):

So testing this in Chrome on Win10, which allows such large numbers.

The code works if I actually subtract ticksInMilliseconds. You added in both cases.

HOWEVER the website you posted does not work on 10000 added.

638315425210000000 is 2023-09-29​T00:02:01.000Z and 1 tick more is
638315425210010000 is 2023-09-29​T00:02:01.000Z which is the same according to the site

Whereas

638338147200000000 is 2023-10-25​T07:12:00.000Z and one tick less

638338147199990000 is 2023-10-25​T07:11:59.999Z IS one millisecond less

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/worldwidewat/TicksToDateTime/issues/1)

```js
let ticksInMilliseconds = 10000
//to add milliseconds to tick
const startTick = "638315425210000000"; // valid INT in Chrome
console.log("str",startTick,"int",+startTick)
const millisecondsAdded = (+startTick) +  ticksInMilliseconds 
//to reduce one millisecond
const endTick = "638338147200000000"
const millisecondReduced = (+endTick) - ticksInMilliseconds

console.log(startTick,millisecondsAdded)
console.log(endTick,millisecondReduced)
```